# Converting GPS heights to AHD heights

Tags: gps, elevation

I was wondering if there is a way to convert heights that are logged from a normal bluetooth GPS to AHD heights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a Geoid model and a program to use it.
This page - http://www.ga.gov.au/geodesy/ausgeoid/ - seems to give you both of these.

I'd also check the GPS to see if it has a similar geoid model built in and can auto-correct. Often they can - but the model is usually very coarse because of size constraints.